# Timestamp source for dpdk-pdump packets on E810 and DPDK 19.11

Tags: dpdk

I am using a Intel E810-XXVDA4 and DPDK version 19.11. During troubleshooting we have captures outgoing traffic with dpdk-pdump:

`dpdk-pdump -- --pdump 'port=1,queue=*,tx-dev=/tmp/tx.pcap'`

I have opened the pcap-file in wireshark and I can see that some packets are delayed. However, system behavior indicates that the delays I see in the pcap file are not correct, they are too big.

My questions is, how is the timestamp on packets in the pcap from dpdk-pdump created, like NIC HW generated, CPU time at disk write etc or something else?

Are there any run-time or build-time options to change the source of the timestamps?

Comment: @rmcarlson can you help to calrify your question? is it `does E810 allow HW timestamp in DPDK? if yes is this same tiemstamp that is copied over to DPDK-pdump secondary process?` or is your question (as per the tile) `DPDK E810 ICE PMD is not capturing the correct timestamp for DPDK-pdump?`.

Comment: Hi! I guess the question is:

**My questions is, how is the timestamp on packets in the pcap from dpdk-pdump created, like NIC HW generated, CPU time at disk write etc or something else?

Are there any run-time or build-time options to change the source of the timestamps?**

Comment: @mcarlsson thanks for clarifying, `can you please update the question TITLE and question explanation` and `please do share the DPDK primary application parameters used for NIC E810` too.

Answer (score 2):

*Answer from dpdk users mailing list, many thanks to S.H*

Follow up.  The older dump-pdump in 19.11 does timestamps when packet is read from the ring which is bad.

You might have better luck with DPDK 20.11 and the dpdk-dumpcap which puts timestamp in when packet is put into ring.

Let me give picture:

```
    Application (primary)
       | 1                       2
       +--+-------------------------> wire
          |                        
          |             dumpcap (secondary)
          +---========--------------> capture file
                                 3
```

The ==== is ringbuffer between processes

1. Where 20.11 with dpdk-dumpcap gets timestamp
2. Where you want the timestamp but is not possible
3. Where 19.11 and dpdk-pdump gets timestamp

Comment: thanks for sharing the answer from DPDK community to help all. Quick followup on the same, `is not capturing or using the timestamp at NIC the accurate measure than what is done to copy the packet ring or when user pciks up from secondary DPDK applciation pdump?`. Also for the part `how is the timestamp on packets in the pcap from dpdk-pdump created, like NIC HW generated, CPU time at disk write etc or something else?` as mentioned in my comment `are you expecting TIMESYNC from E810 to be placed in DPDK mbuf timestamp. Currently I do not see HW offlaod feature with E810` too.